# RestKit Map values from nested dictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, json, restkit

I am getting JSON response like this

```
{
    "id" : 12345
    "course_name" : "history",
    "teacher" : "joy",
    "region" : {
                   "code" : "Al",
                   "name" : "Alabama"
               }
}
```

I have a course entity in coredata and a respective model in code as "MKCourse" this entity is like this

```
MKCourse
  - id
  - courseName
  - teacher
  - regionCode
  - regionName
```

I am setting values from nested dictionary in MKCourse like this -

```
mapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class] inManagedObjectStore:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectStore]];
    mapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = YES;
    mapping.setNilForMissingRelationships = YES;

    [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
     @"id", [self modelIdAttribute],
     @"course_name", @"courseName",
     @"teacher", @"teacher",
     @"region.code", @"regionCode",
     @"region.name", @"regionName",
     nil];
```

**But it always set nil to regionCode and regionName.** I don't know what is wrong. Is it possible to get values like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for RestKit 2.+ add the following code:

```
[mapping addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute:@"region"];
```

and try `addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary` method

```
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"id", [self modelIdAttribute],
     @"course_name", @"courseName",
     @"teacher", @"teacher",
     @"region.code", @"regionCode",
     @"region.name", @"regionName"
}];
```

not sure about RestKit 1.0. maybe you can try to separate them:

```
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:[self modelIdAttribute]];
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"course_name" toAttribute:@"courseName"];
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"teacher" toAttribute:@"teacher"];
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"region.code" toAttribute:@"regionCode"];
[mapping mapKeyPath:@"region.name" toAttribute:@"regionName"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this is supported in 0.2 version of Restkit but I am using 0.1 version. Right now I am not in a position to change my code to support the 0.2 version. Any idea on how we can achieve it without addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute ?

Comment: @Mithielsh not sure about RestKit 1.0. try to separate them (have updated the answer)